# What is the fastest way to associate a boolean flag to every possible integer value?

Tags: java, performance, algorithm, data-structures, real-time

If I had a byte instead of an integer, I could easily create a boolean array with 256 positions and check:

```
boolean[] allBytes = new boolean[256];

if (allBytes[value & 0xFF] == true) {
   // ...
}
```

Because I have an integer, I can't have an array with size 2 billion. What is the fastest way to check if an integer is true or false? A set of Integers? A hashtable?

**EDIT1:** I want to associate for every possible integer (2 billion) a true or false flag.

**EDIT2:** I have ID X (integer) and I need a quick way to know if ID X is ON or OFF.

Comment: How do you define "an integer is true"? I am not following the question

Comment: a integer has no true or false state.

Comment: You mean check if a bit of an integer is 1 or 0?

Comment: I want to associate for every possible integer (2 billion) a true or false flag.

Comment: why exactly you want to do that? It seems like an overkill. Maybe tell us why you are doing this and we can suggest a more efficient solution

Comment: @chrisapotek According to what? Arbitrary?

Comment: Exactly what type of algorithm are you thinking of? There may be a better way to do it than storing booleans for every number.

Comment: `BitSet` is what you are looking for.

Comment: I have ID X (integer) and I need a quick way to know if ID X is ON or OFF.

Comment: boolean [] blammy = new boolean[Integer.MAX_VALUE];  use an integer as the index.

Comment: @DwB That's 2 billion. It will blow the memory!

Comment: You can store a set of all integers associated true (or false, whichever set is smaller), and maybe compress that set further.  But it's probably the wrong approach to whatever your actual problem is.

Comment: exactly how long to you think it's going to take your computer to actually populate an array with 2BN values in it?

Comment: 2 billion bytes is 2GB.  Most computers can handle that these days.  If you use a `BitSet` instead, that becomes 2 billion bits instead,  which is a measly 250MB, which you can certainly handle.

Comment: Assuming that this is a real problem, an in-memory solution is unlikely to be an option.  consider a database solution.  one table, two columns.  column 1: integer value (the index), column 2: flag: true or false.

Comment: Whatever the solution, this sounds exactly like an XY problem...

Comment: Is this boolean array going to be dense or [sparse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sparse_array)? (Is this for the Sieve of Eratosthenes?) If dense, use a BitSet, if sparse, use a Map (such as HashMap).

Comment: Last time I checked there where still 2^32 possible Integers, not 2^31.

Comment: @DwB Allocating `new boolean[Integer.MAX_VALUE]` throws on most machines, but the memory needed is a problem for hardly any computer (524 MB when using bits, see my answer).

Comment: @Durandal sure, but half of them are negative...

Comment: @Alnitak Sure, but I'm against discrimination based on stereotypes :) And due to the typical question *quantum fluctuation* TC has *implied* positive integers; still first thing he asks on the first answer is for *negative* integer.

Comment: @DwB no database solution is going to be as efficient as a single chunk of 0.5GB of RAM. Consider how much wasted space a relational table would have - 32 bits for each index value, at least one byte for the boolean value, and then an actual index over the values too!  If you'd made that an answer I'd have downvoted it as hard as possible.

Comment: If your data is sparse, use a HashSet.

Answer (score 3):

A `BitSet` can't handle negative numbers. But there's a simple way around:

```
class BigBitSet {
    private final BitSet[] bitSets = new BitSet[] {new BitSet(), new BitSet()};

    public boolean get(int bitIndex) {
        return bitIndex < 0 ? bitSets[1].get(~bitIndex)
                : bitSets[0].get(bitIndex);
    }

    ...
}
```

The second BitSet is for negative numbers, which get translated via the '~' operator (that's better than simply negating as it works for `Integer.MIN_VALUE`, too).

The memory consumption may get up to 4 Gib, i.e., about 524 MB.

Answer (score 2):

I feel stupid for even elaborating on this.

The smallest unit of information your computer can store is a bit, right? A bit has two states, you want two states, so lets just say bit=0 is false and bit=1 is true.

So you need as many bits as there are possible int's, 2^32 = 4,294,967,296. You can fit 8 bits into a byte, so you need only 2^32 / 8 = 536,870,912 bytes.

From that easily follows code to address each of these bits in the bytes...

```
 byte[] store = new byte[1 << 29]; // 2^29 bytes provide 2^32 bits

 void setBit(int i) {
     int byteIndex = i >>> 3;
     int bitMask = 1 << (i & 7);
     store[byteIndex] |= bitMask;
 }

 boolean testBit(int i) {
     int byteIndex = i >>> 3;
     int bitMask = 1 << (i & 7);
     return (store[byteIndex] & bitMask) != 0;
 }
```

java.util.BitSet provides practically the same premade in a nice class, only you can use it to store a maximum of 2^31 bits since it does not work with negative bit indices.

Comment: It looks like a BitSet will require a huge amount of pre-allocated memory (500 million bytes), correct? I should probably have to stick with a hashtable then. What do you think?

Comment: @chrisapotek no-one can answer until you answer some of the questions you've been asked in other comments, i.e. how sparse is the set, what's it for (there might be a better solution).  Also some answers are for unknown reasons considering negative integers - please clarify the exact range intended.

Answer (score 1):

Since you're using Java, use BitSet. It's fast and easy. If you prefer, you could also use an array of primitive longs or BigInteger, but this is really what BitSet is for.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/BitSet.html

Comment: Can you give a code example of how to do that with BitSet? For example: how do I toggle on and off the integer -23434 ?

Comment: @chrisapotek You need two of them. See my answer.

Comment: @chrisapotek martinus is right -- use one BitSet for the nonnegatives and one for the  negatives.